# Can I add a dataset in CKAN without specifying the actual data link or file?

Tags: ckan

My client wants to use a Data Asset Catalog that is *not* connected with the actual data, since the data is usually classified and the Data Asset Catalog will be in an unclassified environment.  So instead of referencing a link or uploading the data, they'd like to have the "location" field be a text description of the location and not an active link.  CKAN looks great for their needs except for this one point.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To get CKAN to skip the resource adding step, assuming you are using CKAN from source/github clone:

`cd` to your ckan directory, e.g. `/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan`

Then:

```
git remote add smartlane https://www.github.com/smartlane/ckan.git
git fetch smartlane
git merge smartlane/add-dataset-without-adding-data
```

Otherwise you have to apply the changes in [this GitHub comparison](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/compare/master...smartlane:add-dataset-without-adding-data)

Comment: So I'm not after custom fields. CKAN forces you to add either a link or upload the actual data. Can I customize CKAN in some way to skip this step? All I want is to just enter in the basic metadata. Is this possible?

Comment: Ah now I get you. This almost got implemented into CKAN:  https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/2327 and https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/2316. In the absence of that it is possible by writing a small extension, I'll update my answer.